# Using std::enable if for template with 3 generic arguments

Tags: c++, templates, enable-if

I've already found a few threads to the topic of `std::enable_if`, but unfortunately I am not able to apply the examples to my code.

```
template<class From, class To, class Value>
struct convert
{
  static Value apply(Value value)
  {
    return value;
  }
};
```

I want this to be active only when `From` and `To` are the same, so I tried to use

```
std::enable_if<std::is_same<From,To>::value>::Value
```

But that doesn't work. How would I do this?

I also have these two specializations, to give you a better picture of my problem:

```
template<class From, class Value>
struct convert<From, kilometer, Value>
{
  static Value apply(Value value)
  {
    doSomething;
  }
};

template<class To, class Value>
struct convertImpl <kilometer, To, Value>
{
  static Value apply(Value value)
  {
    doSomethingElse;
  }
};
```

This is where my abguity problems come from. Right now I'm static_asserting the case that `From` and `To` are the same thus making the code to compile. But I would like to just return the value when those two are of the same type.

Comment: Want *what* to be active, the entire structure, or specifically the `apply` method?

Comment: The entire structure.

Comment: why don't you specialize it for `<kilometer, kilometer, Value>` ?

Comment: The first code block. Currently I can't convert from say kilometer to kilometer because I have a static_assert the doesn't allow me to do so. But for reasons of comfort and completeness, I want to be able to do this by just returning the value I entered.

Comment: @DenverCoder21: is my answer now what you aim?

Comment: Yes that's about what I had in mind, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class From, class To, class Value>
struct convert
{
    template <typename F = From, typename T = To>
    static auto apply(Value value) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<F,T>::value, Value>::type
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<F, From>::value && std::is_same<T, To>::value, "");
        // no conversion
        return value;
    }

    template <typename F = From, typename T = To>
    static auto apply(Value value) -> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<F,T>::value, Value>::type
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<F, From>::value && std::is_same<T, To>::value, "");
        // do conversion
        return value;
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4958497183c4da6)

Alternatively this can be implemented using a tag-based dispatching:

```
template<class From, class To, class Value>
struct convert
{
    static Value apply(Value value)
    {
        using tag = std::integral_constant<bool, std::is_same<From, To>::value>; 
        return _apply(value, tag{});
    }

private:
    static Value _apply(Value value, std::true_type)
    {
        // no conversion
        return value;
    }

    static Value _apply(Value value, std::false_type)
    {
        // do conversion
        return value;
    }
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98ba713b090c79ef)

Comment: Just because it is possible to use a new language feature, doesn't mean you should. A specialization achieves the same effect, which makes this code needlessly obfuscating.

Comment: @DDrmmr: specialization of entire structure? the snippet in the question is an example.

Comment: @DDrmmr: or maybe *partial specialization of apply member function*? (which FYI does not exist in C++)

Comment: If the actual code contains more members, the function in question can simply forward to an overloaded helper function or a helper struct that is specialized for the particular case. Still much more readable than what you posted IMO.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you want SFINAE for this, from your description I *think* you just want a specialization:

```
template<class From, class To, class Value>
struct convert
{
    static Value apply(Value value)
    {
        Value somethingElse = ...;
        return somethingElse;
    }
};

template<class From, class Value>
struct convert<From,From,Value>
{
    static Value apply(Value value)
    {
        return value; // SAME
    }
};
```

I admit I honestly don't see the sense in this, as `Value` is an independent type from both `From` and `To`, but you probably know something about it which I don't. It would seem this is your desire if you want the full struct specialized. [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/3oa0Pk).

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks this looks promising.